# How can i make a function using cocoalibspotify that checks if track is starred and display the star next to the starred track (TABLE)

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

I want to add an option to my spotify application which using Cocoalibspotify (iOS) that will mark all the Starred song with some image that i'v  made,
the problem is that:
for checking if SPTrack is starred or not i should load the track using SPASYNCLOADING method
which returns void.
so basically for each cell on the table i will take the spotify ID and load the track to know if the track is starred or not.
I wanted to know if there is another way to do it ?
since on those SPASYCNLOADING methods you can't return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're able to put the tracks into a table and have the track's title show up, the track is loaded enough to show whether it's starred or not, so you can just check the `starred` property of the track.

Otherwise, you could do:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = …;
SPTrack *track = …;

[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {

    if (notLoadedItems.count > 0) {
        // Track didn't load, so bail out.
        return;
    }

    if (track.starred) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"starred"];
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
    }
}];
```